# How is joining with a subquery different from joining without a subquery? Looking for difference between two similar queries

Tags: mysql, domo

I want to see which user created floor equipment for which customer -- both of these queries do what I want. The second query, however, results with 700 more rows than the first. Could you please explain the difference?

I ran another query that found the difference between the two sets -- sure enough, this query yielded 700 rows. Therefore, the data output is the same, but somehow the second query catches more results. I tried looking at the additional 700 rows, but they all seemed normal and similar to the other results. I can't find the difference by looking at the code, which is what I'm hoping someone can help me with

First query

```sql
SELECT customer.name, user.name, floor_equipment.id
FROM customer, user, floor_equipment, floor, building, site
WHERE (floor_equipment.floorID = floor.ID AND floor.buildingID = building.id AND
building.siteID = site.id AND floor_equipment.created_by = user.id)
```

Second Query

```sql
SELECT newTable.custName, newTable.userName, newTable.equipID
FROM (SELECT customer.name as "custName", user.name as "userName", 
floor_equipment.id as "equipID", floor_equipment.created_by as "creatorID" 
FROM customer, floor_equipment, floor, building, site 
WHERE (floor_equipment.floorID = floor.ID AND floor.buildingID = building.id AND
building.siteID = site.id AND site.customerID = customer.ID)) as newTable, user 
WHERE user.id = newTable.creatorID
```

I would expect both of these queries to have the same result, however the second query yields 700 more rows than the first. Aside from the extra rows, both queries result in the same data. The 700 additional rows seem to be normal and similar to the other rows.

NOTE:  There is a seemingly pointless subquery in the second query. The purpose of this was for optimization. I am running these queries within Domo, a business intelligence webapp. I wrote the subquery in hopes that it would run faster. Because of the way Domo works, the former took 2 hours whereas the latter took 45 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring (or perhaps rectifying) the syntax errors, your first query can be written as follows:

```
SELECT c.name
     , u.name
     , fe.id
  FROM customer c
 CROSS 
  JOIN user u
  JOIN floor_equipment fe
    ON fe.created_by = u.id
  JOIN floor f
    ON f.ID = fe.floorID 
  JOIN building b
    ON b.id = f.buildingID 
  JOIN site s
    ON s.id = b.siteID
```

Likewise, written a little more coherently, your second query is as follows:

```
SELECT x.custName
     , x.userName
     , x.equipID
  FROM 
     ( SELECT c.name custName
            , u.name userName
            , fe.id equipID
            , fe.created_by creatorID
         FROM customer c
         JOIN site s
           ON s.customerID = c.ID
         JOIN building b
           ON b.siteID = s.id 
         JOIN floor f
           ON f.buildingID = b.id 
         JOIN floor_equipment fe
           ON fe.floorID = f.ID 
      ) x
   JOIN user u
     ON u.id = x.creatorID
```

Again, we can omit the subquery and write it thus...

```
       SELECT c.name custName
            , u.name userName
            , fe.id equipID
            , fe.created_by creatorID
         FROM customer c
         JOIN site s
           ON s.customerID = c.ID
         JOIN building b
           ON b.siteID = s.id 
         JOIN floor f
           ON f.buildingID = b.id 
         JOIN floor_equipment fe
           ON fe.floorID = f.ID 
         JOIN user u
           ON u.id = fe.created_by
```

...so we can see that the first query had a cartesian product (CROSS JOIN), whereas the second query does not.

Comment: The first query doesn't cross join, that is the difference.

Comment: Ah, yeah, just noticed that; the first cross joins _less_; the latter one dropped the `floor_equipment.created_by = user.id` condition in the subquery.

Comment: See amended answer.

Comment: Do you have an idea as to which query is logically correct for the problem I am trying to solve? My desire is to pair each floor_equipment entry with the customer who owns it and the user who created it.

Comment: I can't say that query 2 is correct, but query 1 is surely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a Cartesian product between the tables:

```
   customer, user, floor_equipment, floor, building, site
```

and your where condition is not for a join but just for a tuple of Boolean value

```
 floor_equipment.floorID = floor.ID,    
    floor.buildingID = building.id,
      building.siteID = site.id, 
      floor_equipment.created_by = user.id 

      ( boolean,  boolean, boolean, boolean)
```

each boolean is the result for the corresponding match eg:

```
          floor_equipment.floorID = floor.ID
```

so practically return all the rows because have not matching counterpart.

In the second, your first Cartesian product is expanded by the join  between the first result and the matching rows for user.id and newTable.creatorID. Looking to your code, it could be that you need an explicit join syntax and proper on condition.